# JavaScript: Uncaught Typerror on parseFloat in input type text

Tags: javascript, razor, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

Hi I got the error `Uncaught Typerror on parseFloat in input type text` and I cannot find a solution

I'm trying to make this function above when a do the parseFloat on field txtJurosBaixa2 i got the error if I put the code on browser console this run fine but on function he crashed.

on code `var jrBaixa = isNaN(parseFloat($("#txtJurosBaixa2").val().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'))) ? 0 : parseFloat($("#txtJurosBaixa2").val().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'));`

this part going fine

```
isNaN(parseFloat($("#txtJurosBaixa2").val().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'))) ? 0
```

but this one don't

```
: parseFloat($("#txtJurosBaixa2").val().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'));
```

the Value from txtJurosBaixa2 is "0,00"

My Code is

```
function CalculaValores () {
    var formato = { minimumFractionDigits: 2, style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL'    
    var vlrFatura = isNaN(parseFloat($("#txtValorFatura").val().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'))) ? 0 : parseFloat($("#txtValorFatura").val().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'));
    var vlrDesc = isNaN(parseFloat($("#txtDesconto").val().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'))) ? 0 : parseFloat($("#txtDesconto").val().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'));
    var vlrJuros = isNaN(parseFloat($("#txtJuros").val().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'))) ? 0 : parseFloat($("#txtJuros").val().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'));
    var tarifa = isNaN(parseFloat($("#txtTarifaBanc").val().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'))) ? 0 : parseFloat($("#txtTarifaBanc").val().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'));
    var arrend = isNaN(parseFloat($("#txtArredondamento").val().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'))) ? 0 : parseFloat($("#txtArredondamento").val().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'));
    var descImp = isNaN(parseFloat($("#txtDescontoImposto").val().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'))) ? 0 : parseFloat($("#txtDescontoImposto").val().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'));
    var jrBaixa = isNaN(parseFloat($("#txtJurosBaixa2").val().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'))) ? 0 : parseFloat($("#txtJurosBaixa2").val().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'));
    var descBaixa = isNaN(parseFloat($("#txtDescontoBaixa").val().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'))) ? 0 : parseFloat($("#txtDescontoBaixa").val().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'));
    var vlrTotal = 0;  
        if (vlrJuros !== 0)
            vlrTotal = vlrFatura * (vlrJuros / 100);
        else
            vlrTotal = vlrFatura;

        if (jrBaixa !== 0)
            vltTotal = vltTotal * (jrBaixa / 100);

        vlrTotal = vlrTotal + tarifa + arrend;
        vlrTotal = vlrTotal - (vlrDesc + descBaixa + descImp);

        $("#txtValorLiquido").val(vlrTotal.toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato).replace("R$", ""));
}
```

The Error I get is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
    at parseFloat (<anonymous>)
    at Object.CalculaValores (ManutencaoFatura.js:415)
    at Object.<anonymous> (ManutencaoFatura.js:399)
    at j (DXR.axd?r=1_228-Qa59g:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (DXR.axd?r=1_228-Qa59g:2)
    at x (DXR.axd?r=1_228-Qa59g:5)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (DXR.axd?r=1_228-Qa59g:5) CalculaValores    @   ManutencaoFatura.js:415 (anonymous) @   ManutencaoFatura.js:399 j   @   DXR.axd?r=1_228-Qa59g:2 fireWith    @   DXR.axd?r=1_228-Qa59g:2 x   @   DXR.axd?r=1_228-Qa59g:5 b   @   DXR.axd?r=1_228-Qa59g:5 XMLHttpRequest.send (async)      send   @   DXR.axd?r=1_228-Qa59g:5 ajax    @   DXR.axd?r=1_228-Qa59g:5 $.ajax  @   DXR.axd?r=17_42-cb59g:663 RemoverDoc    @   ManutencaoFatura.js:376 onclick @   ManutencaoFatura:1
```

All values are `0.00`

Comment: I edited your post to fix the formatting, but please edit your question to make more clear what you are doing, what's happening and what's your question. A large block of code and a backtrace do not make a good question.

Comment: `isNaN(parseFloat($("#txtValorFatura").val().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'))) ? 0 : parseFloat($("#txtValorFatura").val().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'));` is the same as `parseFloat($("#txtValorFatura").val().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.')) || 0;`

Comment: You're missing a closing curly brace on a `formato` object. Also, I would recommend reducing code duplication by defining a function for number formatting. There is a lot of `$("#txtValorFatura").val().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.')` type of code, which makes reasoning hard. Also try to cache values in variables. Sorry, nothing substantial on the subject, but I hope those tips will be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Andreas using your comment and adding some values I got the solution

var jrBaixa = parseFloat($("#txtJurosBaixa2").val().replace(/./g, '').replace(',', '.').replace('R$', '').trim()) || 0;

know it's working fine thank you